# JavaScript Password check and Open .html file if correct

Tags: javascript

I need to open a .html file upon password being entered correctly, the file is in the same folder. I have gotten most of it to work but it now says that my password function is not a function. Any help would be much appreciated

my code-

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Login</title>

</head>

<body onLoad="SetTime()">
<form name="form1">
<label for="password">Enter Password</label>
<input type="password" name="Password" id="password">
<input type="button" onClick="Password()" value="Submit" id="btn"> 
</form>
<script>

var password = "JavaScript";
var userInput = document.getElementById("password").value;
function SetTime()
{
  setTimeout("closeWindow()",120000);

}

function closeWindow(){
window.close();

}

function Password() {

if (userInput == "JavaScript") {
    window.open("file:///outcome 3.html")

    }
    }

</script>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First. I hope you know this is not secure. Second, your issues is the fact that your element id/name and function names are the same. Change one of them.

Third, you only read the value when the page is loaded. It does not magically get updated, you need to read the value of the textbox inside of the function.

Comment: You are right solved it, only issue is it's not finding the html file.

Comment: I changed it to window.open("outcome3.html") and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open html file like this "file:///outcome 3.html". Please check path of login html and path of redirected html --> define relative path to open.

Comment: I changed it to window.open("outcome3.html") and it works now.

Comment: Because 2 html files are contained in only one folder.